# Unable to parse Json Object in Java

Tags: java, json

Below is the sample code:

```
    import org.json.JSONArray
    import org.json.JSONObject

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("{\"Status\":200,\"Description\":\"Success\",\"Result\":\"{\\\"Id\\\":\\\"ABCD123\\\",\\\"clientId\\\":\\\"0c34c71c\\\",\\\"status\\\":\\\"Finished\\\",\\\"message\\\":\\\"Done\\\",\\\"type\\\":\\\"registration\\\"}\"}")
    
    /* 
     here I want to do something like:
       JSONObject innerJsonObj = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("Result");
       String id = innerJsonObj.get("clientId");
    */
```

On executing JSONObject innerJsonObj = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("Result"); - it gives:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast object '{"Id":"ABCD123","clientId":"0c34c71c","status":"Finished","message":"Done","type":"registration"}' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'org.json.JSONObject'

So what modification I need to do for fetching the values present in nested JsonObject( i.e Result)

Comment: Your json is wrong. Json object syntax is "key1" : {"key2": "value"} not "key1" : "{"key2": "value"}"

Comment: @hiimjames, I modified Json now.

Comment: Your JSON contains a String value that itself is JSON. You need to reparse that.

Comment: this is correct json you are looking for JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("{\"Status\":200,\"Description\":\"Success\",\"Result\":{\"Id\":\"ABCD123\",\"clientId\":\"0c34c71c\",\"status\":\"Finished\",\"message\":\"Done\",\"type\":\"registration\"}}");

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON:

```
{
    "Status": 200,
    "Description": "Success",
    "Result": "{\"Id\":\"ABCD123\",\"clientId\":\"0c34c71c\",\"status\":\"Finished\",\"message\":\"Done\",\"type\":\"registration\"}"
}
```

As you can see, the value of `Result` is a string, not a JSON object.
So you'd need to create a new `JSONObject` from that string:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("{\"Status\":200,\"Description\":\"Success\",\"Result\":\"{\\\"Id\\\":\\\"ABCD123\\\",\\\"clientId\\\":\\\"0c34c71c\\\",\\\"status\\\":\\\"Finished\\\",\\\"message\\\":\\\"Done\\\",\\\"type\\\":\\\"registration\\\"}\"}");

JSONObject innerJsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonObject.getString("Result"));
String id = innerJsonObj.getString("clientId");
```